# Whats happening to my HTML?

Tags: php, html, validation, doctype

I am making changes to my website, and I just noticed that things look different. In IE, the content doesn't center, there's a margin on my content, and the font looks bigger in chrome..

I ran it through Yahoo's HTML validator and the error I get is `line 1 - Error: character "" not allowed in prolog`. I believe that there may be some sort of whitespace being sent before the DOC TYPE, but I cant seem to fix it. The HTML looks fine in my text editor (Notepad++) so I don't know what the problem is. I'm using a strict DOC Type. Everything was fine before I made any changes, but I can't pinpoint what caused the change.

If it helps, I'm using a Framework (Kohana). My initial thought was that something was being sent to the browser by an echo or something, but I couldn't find any echo statements.

I don't know what could be causing this... If you want to see any code or HTML just ask.

**Here's the HTML (only head and doctype) via the page source in Google Chrome**

There seems to be some foreign characters in the source that I've never seen before, yet don't show up anywhere else (yahoo, or otherwise)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>Recent Debates - Clashing Thoughts</title> 

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="description" content="Clashing Thoughts is a great place to argue! Search topics you feel passionate about, pick where you stand on the issue and get your point across. The votes are tallied up for every debate so you can even see which side is most popular." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="debates, arguments, topics, popular topics, popular debates, surveys, choices" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/css/master.css" media="screen" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/css/clashingthoughts.css" media="screen" /> 
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://localhost/images/favicon.ico" /> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://localhost/images/favicon.ico" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</head>
```

Comment: Nobody can help unless you show the code.

Comment: this passed fine at http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: Yeah, I found the error... My editor was encoding in UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 as such is fine, in fact, it's what you want. You just don't want the BOM character. BTW, you can pretty much blame Microsoft for using a BOM character in UTF-8 documents. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your source possibly saved in "UTF8 [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)"? Wouldn't be the first time a leading BOM character is tripping up a parser. Try to save it as "UTF8 no-BOM" (may be called differently in your editor).

Comment: That was it, Great Catch... Thanks

Comment: I would never have even though of that.